# PHP Unknown Error at line 0

Tags: php, pdo

> Warning: PHP Startup: PDO: Unable to initialize module Module compiled
>   with module API=20100525 PHP compiled with module API=20131226 These
>   options need to match in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: pdo_sqlite: Unable to initialize module Module
>   compiled with module API=20100525 PHP compiled with module
>   API=20131226 These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: pdo_mysql: Unable to initialize module Module
>   compiled with module API=20100525 PHP compiled with module
>   API=20131226 These options need to match in Unknown on line 0

I have tried for 3-4 hours searching google but i found no help,
These errors have appeared out of nowhere I had moved the website to another server about a year ago. But since than the website has been working. I did update the PHP version from 5.4 to 5.6.3 about a month ago. But since then the website has been working.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: You're absolutely sure that you didn't change anything to make this start happening?

Comment: Yes. I did not do anything i just checked it today and the website showed the errors.

Comment: is this a shared hosting or VPS?

Comment: This is on a  Cloud Hosting

Comment: Contact your hosting company

Comment: In principle it says that the three extensions (e.g. modules) - PDO, pdo_sqlite, pdo_mysql - are compiled using the old API version, e.g. 20100525 (corresponding to PHP 5.4), whereas the new PHP engine (5.6.3) works with extensions compiled with the new API 20131226 (corresponding to PHP 5.6). Your hosting provider should ensure that the new PHP engine uses the proper extensions, e.g. the extensions compiled with the same API version as the PHP engine: 20131226. You said that it already worked for a month now, with the new PHP version. So, I think the provider had a problem lately. Call them.

Comment: Thanks. I contacted them the configured the php.ini to not show warnings. Thanks For Your Help.

Comment: You need to contact the hosting provider in regards to this issue.